# Handlebars Helper Function not returning multiple classes correctly

Tags: meteor, return, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars helper function that takes in a numeric value and needs to return a set of classes associated with that value back to either the *div* block or the full  statement in my html:

e.g. snippet below:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('text', function(num) {

    switch(num.toString()){
        case "3": 
            return "three double dice";
            break;
```

The helper function works. Slight problem. When it attaches it to my *div* in my DOM, for some reason only the first word appears as my class attribute. i.e.

```
HTML(DOM): <div class="two" double dice>
```

or if i rearrange my return statement:

```
HTML(DOM): <div class="double" two dice>
```

I have tried to return the entire div line. i.e.

```
return '<div class="two double dice">'
```

as well as declaring variables in my helper function:

```
return "<div class="+ numClass + doubleClass + diceClass + ">"
```

and even as a handlebars safeString:

```
return new Handlebars.SafeString("<div class="+ numClass + doubleClass + diceClass + ">");
```

*Please can somebody tell me what the correct way to return multiple classes using the handlebars helper function is? Appreciated.*

***Updated(18/03/14):***

To include the template. So depending on which version of the helper function above you use it is either.

```
<template name="threeDice">
    <div class={{text Roll.dice1}}>
        *Content*
    </div>
</template>
```

or

```
<template name="threeDice">
    {{text Roll.dice1}}
        *Content*
    </div>
</template>
```

or even:

```
<template name="threeDice">
    <div class= {{text Roll.dice1}} "double dice">
        *Content*
    </div>
</template>
```

if i change the helper function to only return the "number" string.

Comment: How are you calling the helper from the html?

Comment: Indeed - you really need to post the html template code to allow this to be diagnosed.

Comment: @ Firo @richsilv. Updated to include the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper code seems to be correct, so most probably the error is in how you call it. For the helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('classes', function(num) {
  if(num.toString() === '3') return 'three double dice';
});
```

The correct call should be

```
<div class="{{classes 3}}">
```

Comment: His helper already receives all three class names, but only the first in the class property and the others outside, as he pointed out: `<div class="two" double dice>`

Comment: @Hubert OG is correct. My template call didn't have the additional quotations outside the handlebars expression. When I include the quotations i.e. "{{text Roll.dice1}}", all 3 names appear within the class attribute instead of just the first name. cheers.